# Neatbeans makefile: Trouble compiling .h files

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, g++, header-files

I recently started using Netbeans and I find it good to work with. 
Now the only problem I see is when I create a c++ header file(let's say TestFile.h) the compiler complains with the following text:
`build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/TestFile.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

I have already put TestFile.h into the Header folder but it does not seem to help

I am getting desperate and everything I found did not help me any further. I am not experienced with makefiles.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile a header to begin with?

Comment: I've found not to do it, but I do not know where to change the headers not to compile with

Comment: You just `#include` the headers in your `.cpp` (or whatever ending you use) files, put them somewhere the compiler can find them and that's it. You just compile the `.cpp` files, not the headers.

Comment: I will list what I've done. I created a new project, added a main.cpp(, added an external library) ,added a .h file, added the line #include "TestFile.h" in the main and the compilation does not work with the former error. I am sort of confused :(

Answer (score 0):

After wanting to go to bed 1 hour ago, I finally found out why my program was not compiling. As already said it's the fault that I also compiled header files (.h). But me, not knowing how to change it thought it was simply: move them to the header files folder. But after looking into the tools/Options/C++/Other I've found that in "C++ File" and "C++ Header File" there was a "h". Of course I removed the "h" from the "C++ File" list and after cleaning i could finally compile it.

Comment: Make sure you do **not** move your custom header file into your compiler's standard header file folder.  Never add or remove files from that folder -- instead create your own header file folder, move your headers there, and instruct the compiler to search your folder for include files (in addition to searching the compiler's set of include files).